# Log in globally without HTML 5

Tags: feature-request, login

can we have a Wikipedia-style global login that works even for people without HTML5 and possibly even without JavaScript?

Wikipedia seems to do it like this: when you login, they show you a success page with several images (icons of their daughter sites); the image URL itself contains enough information to log you in there, so it will basically log you in there nōninteractively as soon as your browser loads the image. (If I understand this correctly.)

This would be a nice fallback to have.

(Meh. And I would love to use the site with Lynx, but I think there’s more problems than that. This question pertains to Opera 9, which is about the newest somewhat-reliable “modern” webbrowser I can get on my OS.)

Comment: See this question: [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/152515) The officially supported browsers support HTML5, and the devs appear to have limited interest in supporting previous versions. You should probably look to upgrading your OS.

Comment: True. But this does not prevent people from still adding stuff that’s just not formally supported but still works (“don’t just break because you can”). That’s why I labelled it as “feature request”, since it’s apparently not a bug, just a “would be nice if the devs could do it for me – and, maybe, others”. As for upgrading – I do run the latest version of that OS (in fact, I *develop* it), it’s just not GNU or something. (I do have GNU at work, I don’t enjoy either the OS or the “modern” browsers much.)

Comment: It's not so much "don't break just because you can", it's "it doesn't matter if it breaks because support for modern browsers is more important than attempting to support legacy browsers and people can upgrade" (or something like that). They do some degree of graceful degradation for old browsers, but their lack of support is just that: a lack of support. Opera 9 isn't _explicitly_ unsupported yet - which would mean they explicitly have zero interest in doing anything to support it - but Opera 8 _is_ explicitly unsupported, so it might not be long until Opera 9 is too.

Comment: I’d really love if they wouldn’t do that. Anyway, the technical solution the Wikipedia people did is, technologically, interesting (at least to me as a programmer), so if nothing else it’s been shared with the SO developers now, maybe they have fun with it.